# How to use Coffeescript and shellJS to write executable shell scripts?

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, coffeescript, shebang

I've installed coffeescript and shellJS, using NPM. I have a test script, shtest.coffee:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/coffee
require 'shelljs/global'
echo 'hello'
exit 1
```

Running the script with coffee works fine:

```
$ coffee shtest.coffee
hello
```

Or with shjs:

```
$ shjs shtest.coffee
hello
```

But not directly:

```
$ chmod u+x shtest.coffee
$ ./shtest.coffee
./shtest.coffee: line 2: require: command not found
hello
```

Changing the shebang to point to `/usr/local/bin/js` doesn't help.

It looks like the script is being run as a bash script. What am I doing wrong? OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: Where is your 'coffee' installed?  Is there, for example, a 'coffee' file in /usr/local/bin?

Comment: Well, yes, of course. `which coffee` -> `/usr/local/bin/coffee`

Comment: Does `#!/usr/local/bin/coffee` work with an other simple coffee script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using

```
#!/usr/bin/env coffee
```

as your shebang line. That works for me at least, though I'm not sure why exactly (apart from it having to do with the ENV somehow)

Comment: Hmm, it possibly has to do with the apparent requirement that the interpreter pointed to must not itself be a script ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix) ). `coffee` is a script that begins `#!/usr/bin/env node`. Maybe.

Comment: @SteveBennett Didn't know that, but it does seem like a reasonable explanation